# Transform ee.ImageCollection to xr.Dataset in Python (via Colab)

Tags: google-earth-engine, landsat, google-earth-engine-python-api, xarray

I am trying to transform an `ee.ImageCollection` (Landsat) for a Region of Interest into an `xr.Dataset` so I can further process the data and ultimately export as a `.csv`. I have tried using the library `wxee`. However, values in the resulting xarray only show for certain coordinates, I think because there seems to be a scaling_factor of 1 instead of the true scale of each spectral band (that may be nonsense, but I can't see an alternative). Can anybody help?

Here is the code I have written and an example of the output:

**Packages**

```
import geopandas as gpd
import json
import wxee
import ee
```

**Authorise access needed by Earth Engine**

```
ee.Authenticate()
ee.Initialize()
```

**Read in shapefile defining Region of Interest**

```
shapefile = gpd.read_file('/Path/To/Shape')
js = json.loads(shapefile.to_json())
roi = ee.Geometry(ee.FeatureCollection(js).geometry())
```

**Import Landsat 8 and 9 collections**

```
# Filter by Region of Interest 

l8 = (ee.ImageCollection('LANDSAT/LC08/C02/T1_L2').filterDate('2013-03-01', '2023-09-30') 
                                                   .filterBounds(roi) 
                                                   .select(['SR_B.']))
l9 = (ee.ImageCollection('LANDSAT/LC09/C02/T1_L2').filterDate('2021-10-31', '2023-09-30') 
                                                   .filterBounds(roi) 
                                                   .select(['SR_B.']))

# Merge the collections
merged_collection = l8.merge(l9)
```

**Transform to xarray using wx.to_xarray()**

```
ds = merged_collection.wx.to_xarray()
```

**Output**
[image]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Assuming you wanted to download the images over your `roi` at a 30m scale, you should use:

```py
ds = merged_collection.wx.to_xarray(
    region=roi,
    scale=30,
)
```

When those parameters aren't provided, `wxee` tries to use the scale and geometry of the collection, which doesn't always work. In this case, it downloaded each image with only 6x5 pixels, which suggests that the scale was *very* large.

Depending on the size of `roi`, the code above may cause an error due to the maximum pixel limitations of Earth Engine, in which case you would need to use a larger scale or a smaller `roi`. If that doesn't work, you could also check out the [Xee](https://github.com/google/Xee) package, which is more flexible with allowing you to process data without downloading the entire collection.

Comment: Hi @Aaron Zuspan, thank you so much for answering. Incidentally, I just discovered the answer to my problem through one of your tutorials, here: https://colab.research.google.com/github/aazuspan/wxee/blob/main/docs/examples/image_collection_to_xarray.ipynb. Was on my way to update this post when I noticed you'd answered.

Comment: Glad you got it working!